# Writing a custom JSON convertor using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, list, generics, deserialization, converters

I have a class structure as following

```
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Person : IPerson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IPersonResult
    {
        List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonResult : IPersonResult
    {        
        public List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to deserialize my json to IPersonResult, as following it gives and error,

```
  var personList = new PersonResult
  {
      Persons = new List<IPerson> {new Person {Name = "Jack"}, new Person {Name = "John"}}
  };
  var jsonnn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personList);
  var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(jsonnn);
```

> "Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."

I have created a custom JsonConvertor using Newtonsoft library as follows,

```
public class JsonInterfaceConverter<TInterface, TConcrete> :  CustomCreationConverter<TInterface> where TConcrete : TInterface, new()
    {
        public override TInterface Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return new TConcrete();
        }
    }
```

that works fine with single object, But I need a generic converter that takes care of List of Interfaces while deserialization.

**Somehow, this is what I an trying to achieve**

```
public class JsonListInterfaceConverter<TInterface, TConcrete> : CustomCreationConverter<IList<TConcrete>> where TConcrete:TInterface 
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                reader.Read();
                var value = new List<TConcrete>();

                while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    var item = JObject.Load(reader);
                    value.Add(item.ToObject<TConcrete>());
                    reader.Read();
                }
                return value;
            }
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        public override IList<TConcrete> Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return new List<TConcrete>();
        }
    }
```

that can be used as an attribute on

```
public class PersonResult : IPersonResult
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonListInterfaceConverter<Ilist<IPerson>, List<Person>>))]
        public List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can not create list of `IPerson` without binding interface to any type

Why do you even need `PersonResult`? Just use this instead:

`var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonnn);`

Also this should work for your example (the simplest way with no custom type binders):

```
var personList = new PersonResult
{
    Persons = new List<IPerson> {new Person {Name = "Jack"}, new Person {Name = "John"}}
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personList, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
});

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(serialized, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve on the structure given above

var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(jsonnn);

Comment: Your suggestion is valid if my class has only 1 list attribute. But if PersonResult has multiple Lists i.e. 
IList<IPerson> Persons {get;set}
IList<ITask> Tasks {get; set;}

then certainly I need this custom converter. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: var personList = new PersonResult
  {
      Persons = new List<IPerson> {new Person {Name = "Jack"}, new Person {Name = "John"}}
  };
  var jsonnn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personList);
  var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(jsonnn);

Comment: this is same object I serialize and then from the same JSON, I'm trying to deserialize into the same object!!

Comment: oops i've missed something. just added a example with JsonSerializerSettings

Comment: I only have a serialized response coming from a service call in the form of JSON. I just wanted to deserialize a JSON object that matches my class structure. Anyways I have found a solution to my problem and I truly appreciate your help :) I will post my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done

```
 public class JsonListInterfaceConverter<TInterface, TConcrete> : CustomCreationConverter<IList<TConcrete>> where TConcrete:TInterface 
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                reader.Read();
                var value = new List<TConcrete>();

                while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    var item = JObject.Load(reader);
                    value.Add(item.ToObject<TConcrete>());
                    reader.Read();
                }
                return new List<TInterface>(value.Cast<TInterface>()); //This part I was doing wrong
            }
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        public override IList<TConcrete> Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return new List<TConcrete>();
        }
    }
```

Now I can use this as an attribute on my IList in the class

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}    
public interface ITask
{
    string TaskName { get; set; }
}
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Task: ITask
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
}
public interface IPersonResult
{
    List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class PersonResult : IPersonResult
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonListInterfaceConverter<IPerson, Person>))]
        public List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonListInterfaceConverter<ITask, Task>))]
        public List<ITask> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

**Now when I deserilize it as following, it gives me exactly what I wanted**

```
IPersonResult person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(personResultJSON);
```